# Colouring the surface between lines in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am making a 3D plot in gnuplot. I am drawing three lines that form a triangle in space. Is there any way to colour of fill the triangle they form?

```
set style line 6 lc rgb 'green' pt 7 ps 6  dt (2,4,2,4) lw 2

set arrow from -0.6666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 1.7040257344605167 to 0.20784800000000003, 0.36612, 0.4082358795271838 nohead ls 6
set arrow from 0.20784800000000003, 0.36612, 0.4082358795271838 to 0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666, 0.6085806194501847 nohead ls 6 

set arrow from 0.20784800000000003, 0.36612, 0.4082358795271838 to -0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666, 0.8520128672302584 nohead ls 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define polygons in gnuplot (for which you can define a fill style). This might solve your problem:

```
set object 1 polygon from \
    x1, y1, z1 to \
    x2, y2, z2 to \
    x3, y3, z3 to \
    x1, y1, z1

set object 1 fc rgb '#000000' fillstyle solid lw 0
```

Here is a working example (including your arrows). (I had to modify the coordinates to obtain a closed triangle):

```
set style line 6 lc rgb 'green' pt 7 ps 6  dt (2,4,2,4) lw 2
x1=-0.6666666666666666
y1=0.3333333333333333
z1=1.7040257344605167
x2=0.20784800000000003
y2=0.36612
z2=0.4082358795271838
x3=0.3333333333333333
y3=0.6666666666666666
z3=0.6085806194501847
set arrow from x1, y1, z1 to x2,y2,z2 nohead ls 6
set arrow from x2,y2,z2 to x3,y3,z3 nohead ls 6 
set arrow from x3,y3,z3 to x1, y1, z1 nohead ls 6 

set object 1 polygon from \
    x1, y1, z1 to \
    x2, y2, z2 to \
    x3, y3, z3 to \
    x1, y1, z1

set object 1 fc rgb '#000000' fillstyle solid lw 0

set xrange[-1:1]
set yrange[-1:1]
set zrange[-1:1]

splot -10:-10:-10
```

The output looks like this:[image]